# Where is qgis getting the NO DATA value from?

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, nodata

I have a project that contains an 8-bit paletted layer (call it the mask layer)  and a float 32 single band layer (call this the clip layer). I create a new raster by using the raster calculator, defining the extent to match the clip layer, and the value is defined as

(mask@1 >= 0) * clip@1

The resulting raster, when viewed with gdalinfo, has a NoData value of -3.4028234... e+038. Yet the input clip layer has no NoData value. Where is QGIS getting this NoData value from?

Comment: Have you noticed that -3.4028234...e+38 (which is a base-10 representation of (2 - 2^(-23))*2^127 up to 24 bits of precision) would be represented as the 32-bit binary value 11111111111111111111111111111111B in [single-precision floating point format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)?

Comment: I assumed it was the min value for the datatype, though I didn't look it up. So I guess that's sort of a "yes" :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the default NoData value for QGIS.  It is the smallest possible value for a signed 32-bit float data type (I think you meant to type a minus in front of the value you quoted).  You need not worry about a NoData value appearing especially if non of your data is NoData.  QGIS won't suddenly allocate some data cells as NoData.  It is just part of the definition of the raster - you can always change it if you want some other value, though since you don't have any NoData, it is a bit irrelevant.